# Justification for terrorism

Tags: quran

It is common knowledge today that Extremist groups such as Al Qaeda (a Muslim group) blew up the towers. Is there any source of this carry out terrorist attacks in multiple areas of the Quran? I have heard that Muslims say that Allah told them to do it world. Is this true?

> 1. Do they base their actions on verses in the Quran? If so which ones? Why do they claim to be justified?
> 2. Does this confirm to Islamic ideology?

Comment: See 8:12. It says, "I will cast terror into the hearts of those who disbelieve. Therefore strike off their heads and strike off every fingertip of them"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, no serious Muslim claims that Allah told them personally to do something specific. Muslims believe that revelation ended with the Qur'an and with the Prophet Muhammad (saws). Allah's message for humanity is contained in the Qur'an. This message has zero tolerance for the killing of innocent human beings and terrorism in general. There is no religious justification for what happened that day.

Whoever perpetrated that act did so out of geopolitical motivations, not religious ones.

Muslims remember their Lord at every moment of the day, from waking up to eating to working to sleeping. This by itself is no evidence of fanaticism or extremism. As for launching missiles or suicide bombing, other answers will provide evidence of why these actions are prohibited in Islam.

Answer (score 8):

Islam is a message to all the mankind and for all the time. Islam is based on Qur'an and the tradition of the Messenger and slave of Allah, Muhammad ibn Abdullah (Peace and blessing upon him) to whom Qur'an was revealed. The revelation is complete and the religion of Islam is complete with the death of the Messenger. Islam is free from imperfections and it was revealed to the humanity to follow. However, human beings are not perfect. They make mistakes. All the muslims strive to follow the perfect teachings of Islam.

So what does the perfect teachings of Islam say? The muslims follow the Qur'an and the Qur'an says (emphasis mine):

> ... **whoever kills a soul unless for a soul or for corruption [done] in the
>   land - it is as if he had slain mankind entirely.** And whoever saves
>   one - it is as if he had saved mankind entirely. And our messengers
>   had certainly come to them with clear proofs. Then indeed many of
>   them, [even] after that, throughout the land, were transgressors.
>   **[[Surat Al-Mā'idah:32]](http://quran.com/5/32)**

From the traditions of the Prophet of Islam i.e. hadeeth (which is another source of Islam), it is said:

> Ibn 'Umar (May Allah be pleased with them) reported: Messenger of
>   Allah (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) said, "A believer continues to
>   guard his Faith (and thus hopes for Allah's Mercy) so long as **he does
>   not shed blood unjustly**". [**[Al-Bukhari]**](http://www.sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/220)

Islam is a forgiving religion and asks the muslims to establish justice between themselves and with others. It prohibits oppression. There are several [hadiths](http://www.madeenah.com/article.cfm?id=1174) of the Prophet (peace be upon him) where he advices muslims that oppression is prohibited, so do not oppress anyone and the one who does so is a transgressor against Allah. Islam also places a great emphasis on [kindness](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/262730) and [virtues](http://www.sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/173). Islam asks us to show [forgiveness](http://quran.com/2/109), [enjoin people in good and forbid what is wrong](http://quran.com/3/104). It says that God loves those who pardon and [do good](http://quran.com/3/134) and warns people against [extremism](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/1082210). There are several verses in Qur'an which warns muslims of extremism:

> ...**do not commit excess in your religion** or say about Allah except the
>   truth. **[[Surah An-Nisa:17]](http://quran.com/4/171)**

And in [another verse](http://quran.com/5/77) asks us to not follow those who call to their desires.

Unfortunately, terrorism happens. It happens in all societies because sometimes muslims are ignorant about what their religion tells them. This world has various elements of ignorance, injustice and oppression. Terrorism takes the form of individuals, groups and even sometimes, states. Terrorists do not take their motivations or inspirations from Islam but from elsewhere. They call towards their desires. Islam is not at fault. The terrorists usually have a political motivation and they misquote Qur'an to gather fame and crowd. Suicide bombings, [hijackings or kidnappings](http://www.authentictranslations.com/trans-pub/ae_aaib_3.pdf) are not a part of Islam. Islamic scholars have given [verdicts against such](http://www.authentictranslations.com/trans-pub/ae_saf_10.pdf) [acts of terrorism](http://www.authentictranslations.com/trans-pub/ae_aaib_5.pdf) and they have voiced their [opinion against the perpetrators](http://www.authentictranslations.com/trans-pub/ae_various_1.pdf) of this crime. These are acts of corruption and Allah says in Qur'an that he does not like those who spread corruption in land:

> And when he goes away, he strives throughout the land to cause
>   corruption therein and destroy crops and animals. And **Allah does not
>   like corruption. [[Surah Al-Baqarah:205]](http://quran.com/2/205)**

One thing we should remember is that among those killed in the 9/11 incident were also [innocent muslims](http://islam.about.com/od/terrorism/a/Muslim-Victims-Of-9-11-Attack.htm). How can the terrorists justify their killing when [murder is a major sin](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/1086980)? [This verse](http://quran.com/4/29) in Qur'an asks muslims not to kill one another or themselves. Then how is suicide bombing or any kind of bombing justified? Indeed they are lying against Allah and the messenger and Qur'an says those who invent [lie against Allah](http://quran.com/4/50) are sinners.

Like you, there were [many people](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYQIxuIv7K0) who got interested in Qur'an after incidents like these and they sincerely read Qur'an and found the reality of Islam and became muslims. They found that the Qur'an is completely against what the terrorists claim. The Prophet said "The Qur'an will either be a [proof for you or against](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/1076170) you". The Qur'an is a proof against the terrorists. We hope, you also, sincerely read Qur'an and discover the truth about Islam.

Comment: `he does not shed blood unjustly` So they could kill someone as long as its justified by the community of Muslims and lets say those Muslims really hate Americans and any corruption to america is all right it's like having a religious war to make sure your god wins at the end from what I gather here.

Comment: @SSpoke those kinds of justifications may work in other religions or communities, but in Islam, Muslims can't just decide something just because they feel like it. There are clear laws about what is justified and what isn't. Also, we don't have religious war so that "our god wins" - God is not in need of us. And God does not win by our committing something illegal *according to His own laws*.